# Uso de ng-if e angularjs

Tags: angularjs

resulta que tengo este switch generado de manera dinamica con `ng-repeat`:

```
       <div ng-repeat="model in modelo_final">
         <div style="float:left; padding-right:100px;">
         <div class="can-toggle demo-rebrand-2">
         <input  id={{model.id}} type="checkbox" ng-model="idrecibo[model.id]" ng-change="changeItem(model.id)">
          <label for={{model.id}}>
           <div class="can-toggle__switch" data-checked="{{identificador2}}" data-unchecked="{{identificador}}"></div>
           <div class="can-toggle__label-text"><p style="font-size:15px; width:100px;">{{model.nombre}}</p></div>
           </label>
           </div>
         </div>
       </div>
```

y dentro de todo el funcionamiento que cumple, solo me falta configurar para que cuando abra la pagina me muestre activado los que están activos!, es decir que no siempre vuelva a false al recargar la pagina.

Para saber eso, *model* trae en conjunto a su *id* y *nombre* un *activo* la cual si es 0 esta desactivado, 1 activado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

entonces pense en crear un  `ng-if` y preguntar si es 1 que active los switch pero no encuentro la clase que activa el switch, por lo que investigue parece que activa: `ng-not-empty` y desactiva `ng-empty`

el link del switch [es este](http://codepen.io/personable/pen/stpwD/?utm_source=bypeople). 
Según ustedes como debería hacer el `ng-if`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu switch tiene el `ng-model="idrecibo[model.id]"` por lo tanto es ese valor el que tiene que venir true o false dependiendo si esta activo o no.

Recuerda que segun mi respuesta en una pregunta pasada tuya, para lograr que fueran modelos dinamicos creaste un arreglo `modelo_final`, cuando lo crees hace lo siguiente

```
angular.forEach($scope.modelo_final, function(modulo, index){
   if(modulo.activo == 1){
      $scope.idrecibo[modulo.id] = true;
   }else{
      $scope.idrecibo[modulo.id] = false;
   }
})
```

Comment: el $scope.modulos tendria que ser $scope.modelo_final porque con ese funciono.

Comment: @HernanHumaña exacto, se me paso eso por alto, editare!